# Ansible blockinfile error

Tags: templates, roles, ansible, role

I am trying to use blockinfile, so I am doing some test.
I have the next task, but it give me a sintax error.

```
- name: Prueba
  blockinfile:
  dest: /opt/a
  block: | pruebaa
    pruebaaa
```

This is the error that I have:

```
 ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/home/ikerlan/ansiblePlaybooks/hadoop-Ansible/roles/comun/tasks/main.yml': line 39, column 12, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  dest: /opt/a
  block: | pruebaa
           ^ here
```

My complete main.yml is the next

```
#NAMENODES

#Los siguientes comandos solo se ejecutaran en los namenodes

- name: Archivo de configuracion zoo.cfg
  template: src=zoo.cfg.j2 dest=/opt/zookeeper-3.4.7/conf/zoo.cfg

- name: Prueba
      blockinfile:
      dest: /opt/a
      block: | pruebaa
        pruebaaa

- name: Crear carpeta ZooData
  file: path=/opt/ZooData state=directory mode=0755
  #command: mkdir -p /opt/ZooData/ creates=/opt/ZooData/

- name: Permisos ZooData
  command: chown vagrant /opt/ZooData/

- name: Crear carpeta name
  file: path=/hdfs/name state=directory mode=0755
  #command: mkdir -p /hdfs/name/ creates=/hdfs/name/

- name: Permisos hdfs/name
  command: chown vagrant /hdfs/name/

- name: Crear carpeta journalnode
  file: path=/hdfs/journalnode state=directory mode=0755
  #command: mkdir -p /hdfs/journalnode/ creates=/hdfs/journalnode/

- name: Permisos hdfs/journalnode
  command: chown vagrant /hdfs/journalnode/

- name: Archivo de configuracion slaves
  template: src=slaves.j2 dest=/opt/hadoop-2.7.1/etc/hadoop/slaves
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Are you using ansible 2.0 beta?

Comment: Yes, I am using ansible 2.0.0, is it a  problem? @helloV

Comment: No. I asked because `blockinfile` is supported in 2.0+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have ansible 2.0 to test this. You cannot have any char after **block: |** Try this:

```
  blockinfile:
  dest: /opt/a
  block: |
    pruebaa
    pruebaaa
```

Comment: Thanks it is perfect @helloV

Answer (score 0):

I guess there should be a newline after the `|` character. Also a playbook (or a YAML file in general) must start with `---`.

Comment: I have tryed this but it gives the same error, I only put a part of my yml file, you can see know the complete main.yml. Thanks @tlo